# Vue: Export function to share the logic, template saying it's not imported

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have got a function I want to share the logic of across some different Vue components.

So I have added this to a separate file:

```js
// NormaliseData.js

export default function NormaliseData(value)
{
    switch (value) {
        case 'range':
            return 'Model';
        default:
            const arr = value.split("_");
            for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                arr[i] = arr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + arr[i].slice(1);
            }
            return arr.join(" ");
    }
}
```

I then use this as follows:

```html
<template>
    <div>
       <p>{{ NormaliseData('test function') }}</p>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import NormaliseData from "./NormalizeData";
...
```

However i'm getting the following error:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "NormaliseData" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function should be added to the methods option :

```
<template>
    <div>
       <p>{{ NormaliseData('test function') }}</p>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import NormaliseData from "./NormalizeData";
export default{
methods:{
  NormaliseData 
}

}
</script>
```

to avoid importing that function in every component, you could define it globally in the vue instance then use it in any child component :

**main.js**

```
import NormaliseData from "./NormalizeData";
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.prototype.$NormaliseData =NormaliseData
```

in the component :

```
<template>
    <div>
       <p>{{ $NormaliseData('test function') }}</p>
    </div>
</template>
```